# Calculate two Select Statements in Columns as %

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to combine two Select statements into 2 separate column in one table, then divide them to become %?

```
Select count(*) as 'Quote with VIN' 
From BSIT_ERA_RAW_DATA.dbo.QUOTE  
where LEN(inv_vehicle_id) = 17
```

With the second Select statement below:

```
select count(*) as 'Number of Quote'
from BSIT_ERA_RAW_DATA.dbo.QUOTE
```

The expected result would be something like below:

```
Quote with VIN | Number of Quote | Result
-----------------------------------------
116260         | 195850          | 59.36%
```

Comment: chg'd tag to `sql-server`, a hunch

Comment: thanks guys for the clarification...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to combine the logic from both queries into a single query:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN LEN(inv_vehicle_id) = 17 THEN 1 END) AS `Quote with VIN`,
       COUNT(*) AS `Number of Quote`,
       CONCAT(ROUND(100 * SUM(CASE WHEN LEN(inv_vehicle_id) = 17 THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*), 2),
              '%') AS Result
FROM BSIT_ERA_RAW_DATA.dbo.QUOTE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation.  In MySQL, you can do this with a short-cut:

```
select sum(len(inv_vehicle_id) = 17)) as `Quote with VIN`,
       count(*) as `Number of Quote`
From BSIT_ERA_RAW_DATA.dbo.QUOTE  ;
```

In most other databases you would need to use `case`.

Also, don't use single quotes for column names.  That is a bug waiting to happen.  The best choice is to choose names that don't need to be escaped.  But if you do, use the MySQL escape character (backquotes).